# Laravel 4 and Blade - sections that depends on variables

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I'm facing a serious issue using Blade and Laravel 4, specifically I need to have a section that vary it's content on variables that are handled by a parent section.

To make an example, look at that

controller.php

```
<?php

$data = array('rows' => array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'));
View::make('users-list', $data);

?>
```

users-list.blade.php

```
@extends('base-list')
@section('table-row')
my {{ $row }}
@overwrite
```

base-list.blade.php

```
@section('table')
foreach($rows as $row)
{
    @section('table-row')
    {{ $row }}
    @stop
    @yield('table-row')
}
@show
```

The problem is that I get and undefined variable `$row` because the users-list template is parsed and execute BEFORE the base-list template.

To work-around the problem I did:

base-list.blade.php

```
@section('table')
foreach($rows as $row)
{
    {{ View::make('base-list-row', array('row', $row)) }}
}
@show
```

base-list-row.blade.php

```
{{ $row }}
```

But, seriously, I can't look at that :\

Because the templates are rendered from the child to parent when using @extends I can't even use the `$__env->share('row', $row)` trick because the child is executed before the parent.

Someone has a solution or a better workaround?

Comment: What about using `@include('base-list-row', array($row))` ?

Comment: Tomorrow i'll try but it seems to be the same thing, at least i'll use standard blade syntax ... tnx